# 低品質レビューの、「回答ではありません、コメントです」の削除レビューのコメント文のリンクが英語（本家）

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

低品質レビューで、削除したり、削除を推奨したりした結果表示されるコメント文は、現状次のようになっています。

> これは質問の答えになりません。あなたが[一定の信用度を獲得すれば](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)任意の投稿に[コメントできる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)ようになりますが、それまでは[コメ‌​ントで確認する必要のない回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)を投稿するこ‌​とを検討してください。

これの、「コメントで確認する必要のない回答」の説明リンク先が、英語（というより、本家）です。

特に、何かしら質問に対するアドバイス的なことを投稿してみた、そこまで英語が得意でない新規ユーザーの視点に立つと、これはよろしくない状況だろうな、と思っています。

Comment: MetaSEへのリンクは他にも残ってそうですね……

Comment: @YukiInoue 誰かがそのメタの投稿を和訳してくれたら、リンクを更新します。